# How to show that the consistency of $\Gamma$ does not imply the consistency of $\Delta$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

**Question**

Suppose that $\mathcal L$ has infinitely many constant symbols. Let $\Gamma$ be a set
of $\mathcal L$-formulas, and let
$\quad$$\quad$$\quad$$\quad$$\Delta$ $=$ {$\varphi$ ($x_{i1}$,$x_{i2}$,...,$x_{in}$;$c_{i1}$,$c_{i2}$,...,$c_{in}$)|$\varphi$ ($x_{i1}$,$x_{i2}$,...,$x_{in}$)$\in$$\Gamma$}

Show that:the consistency of $\Gamma$ does not imply the consistency of $\Delta$.

**Hint**

I think we need the Completmess and Soundness, which says a set of formula is consistent iff it is satisfiable.

So we have to construct a formula $\psi$($x_{i1}$,$x_{i2}$,...,$x_{in}$) which is satisfiabe, but $\psi$($x_{i1}$,$x_{i2}$,...,$x_{in}$;$c_{i1}$,$c_{i2}$,...,$c_{in}$) is not satisfiable.

**Summary**

How to construct the formula $\psi$($x_{i1}$,$x_{i2}$,...,$x_{in}$)?

Comment: Is $\varphi(x; c)$ your notation for substituting the constant symbol $c$ for the variable $x$ in the formula $\varphi(x)$? This is very unusual notation. It's much more common to simply write $\varphi(c)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yeah, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L = \{ \prec \} \cup \{ c_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\prec$ is a 2-ary relation symbol, $c_n$ is a constant symbol for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be our fixed set of variables. Let $\Gamma_0$ be the $\{ \prec \}$-theory stating that $\prec$ is a strict total order and let $\Gamma_1 := \{ c_n \prec c_{n+1} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Finally let $\Gamma_2 := \{ x_2 \prec x_1 \}$ and let $\Gamma := \Gamma_{0} \cup \Gamma_{1} \cup \Gamma_{2}$.

$\Gamma$ is consistent because, interpreting $c_n$ as $n$ and $\prec$ as $<$, the assignment 
$$\tau \colon \{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} \to \mathbb{N}, x_n \mapsto \begin{cases}
2 & \text{, if } n = 1 \\
1 & \text{, if } n = 2 \\
n & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is such that
$$
(\mathbb{N}; <, (n \mid n \in \mathbb{N})) \models \Gamma[\tau].
$$

On the other hand
$$
\Delta := \{ \phi[c_1, \ldots, c_n] \mid \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \Gamma \}
$$
is inconsitent, because $c_1 \prec c_2, c_2 \prec c_1 \in \Delta$ and $\Delta$ still states that $\prec$ is a strict total order. Q.E.D.